# Hide Popover controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller, wepopover

In my project i'm using the [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover),
I can able to to call and custom popover with the help of it but, the problem is I can't able to dismiss the popover with a help of button present in the popover.

NOTE:-

- I'm calling the popover from UIBarButtonItem
- The content of the popover is of a view controller
- I'm calling the popover in all the vie'w I'm using it like a help button

I'm calling the popover in all the view's like this

```
if (self.popoverController)
{
[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
self.popoverController = nil;
}
else
{
    NSString * storyboardName = @"MainStoryboard";
    NSString * viewControllerID = @"settings";
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    SettingsViewController * controller = (SettingsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewControllerID];
    self.popoverController = [[WEPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

and I want to dismiss the popover with a help of button which is present in the view controller which has been exposed as a popover.

Need some help as i'm new to IOS developing.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, I guess you have two options.

1. Implement a delegate in your Settings ViewController, to indicate when the help button is pressed, and make parentViewController dismiss the popover
2. Setup a new property in your SettingsViewController to assign the popover

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) WEPopoverController *popoverController;
   ```

Comment: how can i implement the first option.